# Cannot open *.lib Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, libraries

So I'm using Visual Studio 2017. I've already googled the problem and I have a second project which I'm cross-referencing from.
All of the project settings and dependencies are identical, yet the project doesn't build, with the linker error "Cannot open file 'raknet.lib'" or 'raknet_d.lib' (two different files for debug and release versions)

Project settings:

- include directories: "$(SolutionDir)dependencies/raknet/include"
- Additional library directories: "$(SolutionDir)dependencies/raknet/libs"
- linker->input: (debug) "raknet_d.lib" (release) "raknet.lib"

and

[image: dependencies]

Does anyone have any suggestions what I might be missing?

Comment: Check what path is `$(SolutionDir)`.

Comment: It's the correct path. The includes are working... and the evaluation is correct

Comment: Try with absolute path  using `#pragma comment(lib, "c:\mylib\foo.lib")`, v140 and v141 binaries are compatible, check the built toolset of `Raknet.lib` using `dumpbin.exe`.

Comment: Thanks. I think some project settings got crossed over somewhere. I redid my steps in a brand new project and it "magically" worked. VS can be so stupid sometimes